# Solving an or (linear) congruence system

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Usually, when we solve a congruence system, we try to find the general solution that fits the first equation and the second equation and the third, and so on.

How should we solve a congruence system such that we find the general solution that fits the first equation or the second equation or the third, and so on?

I.e. we have:

$\left \{\begin{matrix}
 & x \equiv a_1 \pmod {m_1} & \\ 
 & x \equiv a_2 \pmod {m_2} & \\ 
 & \vdots  &  \\ 
 & x \equiv a_n \pmod {m_n} & 
\end{matrix}\right.$

And we want to find $x$ such that at least one of the equations is true.

E.g.

$\left \{\begin{matrix}
 & x \equiv 1 \pmod {4} & \\ 
 & x \equiv 3 \pmod {4} & 
\end{matrix}\right.$

Should yield the solution $x \equiv 1 \pmod 2$

$\left \{\begin{matrix}
 & x \equiv 1 \pmod {2} & \\ 
 & x \equiv 0 \pmod {3} & 
\end{matrix}\right.$

Should yield $x \equiv 0,1,2,3,5 \pmod 6$

Comment: For your second example, I think $x\equiv 2\pmod 6$ is not a solution. Also it may be worth using De Morgan's Law: $\bigvee p \iff \neg \bigwedge (\neg p)$.